# .do URL opening in Same Tab - html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a URL ending in .do and every time i click the URL, it closes the current application session, and then opens the URL in the same tab instead of opening in a new tab. Can you please suggest how to open this in a new tab?

Code Snippet

```
<p><a href='HTTP://******.com/login.do' target='_blank'>Link_Name</a></p>";
```

Note: This is not a browser issue....as we have almost 10 links in the application and all of them work fine (i.e. open in a new tab) except this one.

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a redirect URL? Confirm what this URL do on server.

Anyways, you can try this

```
<p><a onclick='javascript:window.open("HTTP://******.com/login.do")' href='#'>Link_Name</a></p>";
```

Comment: No, its not a redirect URL. Its just another internal application login page URL.

Comment: hi Gurvinder, unfortunately its not working....any other options that we can try?